# Sphinx csv-table directive produces wrong number of columns

Tags: csv, python-sphinx

I have this simple `csv-table` which should produce a table with just two rows and too columns. Instead it gives me three columns, where as the last column is empty. Why?

```
.. csv-table:: 

    "Inline :math:`a^2+b^2=c^2`","Seperate:
     .. math::

      (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2

      (a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2

      (a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2",
    ".. code-block:: rst

      :math:`a^2+b^2=c^2`",".. code-block:: rst

       .. math::

        (a + b)^2 &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2

        (a-b)^2 &= a^2-2ab+b^2

        (a-b)(a+b)&=a^2-b^2"
```

[image: The HTML Output has three columns]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation is incorrect, and rows should be separated by new lines instead of commas.  This should do it.

```
.. csv-table::

    "Inline :math:`a^2+b^2=c^2`","Separate:

    .. math::

        (a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2

        (a-b)^2 = a^2-2ab+b^2

        (a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2"

    ".. code-block:: rst

        :math:`a^2+b^2=c^2`",".. code-block:: rst

        .. math::

            (a + b)^2 &= a^2 + 2ab + b^2

            (a-b)^2 &= a^2-2ab+b^2

            (a-b)(a+b)&=a^2-b^2"
```

Comment: Works like charm. Many thanks. Still I'm unsure what I did wrong.

Comment: Use diff in your editor to compare the two code samples, or view it online with an [online differ](https://www.diffchecker.com/DkISIJbV).